# Shell programming, looping through files

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to loop through files in a specified directory. But I can't seem to figure out the logic. I am looping through each file and asking if they want to delete that file.

```
#!/bin/bash
dirpath=$1
y=y
Y=Y
echo "changing directory '$dirpath' `cd $dirpath`"

for f in $1/*
do
#####################################
if test -f `ls -1 $1`
then
echo -n "remove file '$f' `ls -1` ?"
read answer
##########################
if test $answer = $y || test $answer = $Y
then

  echo "Processing $f file..."
  echo `rm $f`
    echo "file '$f' deleted "
else
echo "file '$f' not removed"

  fi#2nd if loop
############################  
else
echo 'not a file'
  fi#1st if loop
#######################################

done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `ls`, you already have the filename. Change this:

```
if test -f `ls -1 $1`
```

to:

```
if test -f "$f"
```

Why are you using `echo` and backticks here? Change

```
echo `rm $f`
```

to:

```
rm "$f"
```

Here's another place you're using backticks unnecessarily. Change this:

```
echo "changing directory '$dirpath' `cd $dirpath`"
```

to:

```
echo "changing directory '$dirpath'"
cd "$dirpath"
```

Always quote variables that contain filenames.

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems much more complicated that it should be. Does this fulfill your needs or are you doing some shell practice?

```
rm -iv DIRECTORY/*
```

Comment: That doesn't query the user inquiring whether or not to delete the file

Comment: @shambleh, the -i (interactive) option prompts for confirmation.

Comment: +1 it is good habit to specify directory for rm, even if it is current directory `rm ./*`

Answer (score 2):

You can have `rm` do the "asking" for you via its `-i` flag to prompt user before removal.  I am assuming you want to consider only files, not directories, and not recurse any sub-directories.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $1/* ; do 
    if [ -f $f ] ; then 
        rm -i $f ; 
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the error, can't really help, but it could be written like this, not as verbose though

```
rm -i *
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$1` is a relative path, then once you've `cd`'d into `$1`, the wildcard in your `for` loop will be meaningless. I'd recommend something more like

```
 cd $1
 for f in *; do
    ...
 done
```

Since it will accept both relative and absolute paths.

Moreover, the arguments to the first `test` are wrong. Each time through the loop, $f will hold one filename, so your test should be like

```
 if (test -f $f); then
```

You also repeat this in your `echo` arguments.

The following does basically what you want, with only slight modifications from your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
dirpath=$1
y=y
Y=Y
echo "changing directory '$dirpath' `cd $dirpath`"

for f in ./*; do

if (test -f $f); then
        echo -n "remove file '$f' ?"
        read answer
        if (test $answer == $y) || (test $answer == $Y); then

                echo "Processing $f file..."
                rm $f
                echo "file '$f' deleted "
        else
                echo "file '$f' not removed"
        fi
else
        echo 'not a file'
fi

done
```